# How to disable javadoc spell checker in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I'm used to writing javadoc-style comments for all the public fields and methods in my programs. NetBeans has this annoying habbit of checking how I spell everything in these comments. If it finds a word that it "thinks" it's not ok, it underlines it. I hate it and I want it gone. But I can't find any option to disable it.

Does anyone know any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple google search returned [this](http://www.herikstad.net/2010/07/disabling-spellchecker-in-netbeans.html)

For NetBeans to really understand that you don't want spellchecker, do the following:
Go to

`Tools -> Plugins -> Installed tab -> select the spellchecker plugin -> press Deactivate -> restart NetBeans`

Comment: Thanks, I searched for a solution a lot, don't know how I missed that.